# How to disable SfCalendar horizontal swipe

Tags: flutter, syncfusion-calendar

I'm using the Flutter event calendar day view of [SfCalendar](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar) version 20.3.48. I want to disable the horizontal swipe feature of the widget, only event calendar for a day is required.

```
SfCalendar(
        view: CalendarView.day,
        todayHighlightColor: kPrimaryColor,
        allowDragAndDrop: false,
        allowViewNavigation: false,
        initialDisplayDate: widget.selectedDate,
        initialSelectedDate: widget.selectedDate,
        dataSource: _getAppointments()
      );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `viewNavigationMode`:

```
viewNavigationMode: ViewNavigationMode.none,
```